# Missing Functor and Monad instances when using scala.concurrent.Future with EitherT

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scalaz7

I'm trying to use Scalaz EitherT with a scala.concurrent.Future. When trying to use it in a for-comprehension:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val et1:EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT(Future.successful(1.right))

val et2:EitherT[Future, String, String] = EitherT(Future.successful("done".right))

val r:EitherT[Future, String, String] = for {
    a <- et1
    b <- et2
} yield (s"$a $b")
```

I get the following missing Functor and Monad instances error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.Functor[scala.concurrent.Future]
b <- et2
  ^
could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.Monad[scala.concurrent.Future]
a <- et1
```

Does scalaz define instances for Functor and Monad for Future? If not are there any other libraries that provide these instances or do I need to write them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope. `import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` will get you the [global execution context](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#the-global-execution-context).

Full example:

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  val et1:EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT(Future.successful(1.right))

  val et2:EitherT[Future, String, String] = EitherT(Future.successful("done".right))

  val r:EitherT[Future, String, String] = for {
    a <- et1
    b <- et2
  } yield s"$a $b"

  val foo = Await.result(r.run, 1 seconds)
  // => \/-("1 done")
```

Comment: It works for me. I've updated my answer with the full working example.

Comment: yep, it works! I must have missed something when I tried before. Thanks.

Comment: @danielnixon: When I changed your example to use \/-(1) instead of 1.right it failed.  Do you know why this is?           "no type parameters for method apply: (run: F[scalaz.\/[A,B]])scalaz.EitherT[F,A,B] in object EitherT exist so that it can be applied to arguments (scala.concurrent.Future[scalaz.\/-[Int]])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scalaz.\/-[Int]]
 required: ?F[scalaz.\/[?A,?B]]
lazy val et1:EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT(Future(\/-(1)))                                            ^

Comment: @seanmcl It's because `1.right` returns a `\/` but `\/-(1)` returns a `\/-`. If you want to use the latter, give it an explicit type: `\/-(1): \/[String, Int]`.

Comment: @danielnixon Ah, thanks.  I still haven't grokked subtyping + type classes.

Answer (score 2):

The error is not because of ExecutionContext is missing (it's needed though) but because Scala Future is not a Functor nor a Monad.

The accepted solution works not because of the ExecutionContext but because it imports all the implicits from Scalaz.

This is the line that really fix the problem:

```
import Scalaz._
```

*Also note that using the global execution context it's ok for a test but should not be used on production deployments.*

The problem with that solution is that you import ALL the implicits defined on the library and can make your IDE little bit slow.

On version 7 Scalaz offer the option to import only what you need, using the package `scalaz.syntax`.

Same previous solution with concrete imports:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._

import scalaz._
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._
import scalaz.syntax.either._

val et1:EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT(Future.successful(1.right))

val et2:EitherT[Future, String, String] = EitherT(Future.successful("done".right))

val r:EitherT[Future, String, String] = for {
  a <- et1
  b <- et2
} yield s"$a $b"

val foo = Await.result(r.run, 1 seconds)
foo: String \/ String = \/-(1 done)
```